# How to test functions other than render in a React class using jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to do some `TDD` on a `React` app that I am building.  Using `jest` I am able to test my render function to see if I am getting what I expect to get rendered.  What if I want to test some other function in the class?  How do I get a hold of it?  For example, here is a `React` class:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var React = require('react');
var utils = require('./utils');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    days: function() {
        var days = [];
        var nextMonth = this.daysFromNextMonth(days, numberOfDays);
        return days;
    },
    daysFromNextMonth: function(days, numberOfDays) {
        ...
    },
    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        var days = this.days().map(function(day, i) {
            return <li key={day}>{day}</li>
        return (
            <ul className='monthly-view'>
                {days}
            </ul>
        );
    }
});
```

I want to grab a hold of my `days` or `daysFromNextMonth` functions and see if they are returning what I would expect.  I tried in `jest` to get a hold of the function like this:

```
it('should show an render', function() {
    var result = DailyView.daysFromNextMonth(day, 10)
    ....
});
```

My `error` says that I have no method `daysFromNextMonth`.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to render your component to reference methods on it (akin to instantiating a class before using instance methods):

```
var view = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<DailyView />)
var result = view.daysFromNextMonth(day, 10)
```

Then you can call any of the instance methods.

Answer (score 2):

Using enzyme I found this reference to testing the component's functions,
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/208.

```
const component = shallow(<MyComponent />);
component.instance().foo();
```

You have to get an instance of the component before you can call its methods but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of `jest` and `enzyme` should do the trick. Check out the [jest DOM testing](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#dom-testing) documentation and [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/208#issuecomment-187313486).

Basic idea being you can use `enzyme` to shallow render the components and the manipulate them.