# Unit testing a React function in component

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, components, jestjs

I need a way to unit test the "edit" function in the code below. It is different form the other questions because my function returns no value.

```
class QslTable extends React.PureComponent {
        this.state = {
        data: [{
            key: '0',
            callSign: {
                editable: true,
                value: 'F1ABD',
            },
            QSODate: {
                editable: true,
                value: '10-05-31',
            },
            band: {
                editable: true,
                value: '32',
            },
            mode: {
                editable: true,
                value: 'Phone',
            },
            dxccEntity: {
                editable: true,
                value: 'France',
            },
            delete: {
                editable: false,
                value: 'Delete',
            },
        }],
    };

      edit(index) {
        const { data } = this.state;
        Object.keys(data[index]).forEach((item) => {
            if (data[index][item] && typeof data[index][item].editable !== 'undefined') {
                data[index][item].editable = true;
            }
        });
        this.setState({ data });
    }
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
it('should render the component', () => {
    const renderedComponent = shallow(<QslTable />);

    expect(renderedComponent.find('edit')).toBeDefined();

});
```

The function doesn't return any value. I have no clue how to test the function. I have looked at the documentation for Jest, but couldn't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test functions other than render in a React class using jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252026/how-to-test-functions-other-than-render-in-a-react-class-using-jest)

Comment: The difference is that my function doesn't return any value.